# How to correctly update div during xhrHttpRequest using "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to update value of divToUpdate in same parentDiv where Button is clicked upon successful xhrHttpRequest. I have passed this object as a parameter to the function that sends the xhrHttpRequest but I'm unable to update the div: divToUpdate

```
<div class="parentDiv" >
    <div class="divToUpdate" style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="button" type="button" >Update</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="parentDiv" >
    <div class="divToUpdate" style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="button" type="button">Update</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS Code (minimal sample code)

```
$(function()
{     
  function bindKeyPress() 
  {
    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
      switch(event.which) {
        case 37:  // left
          //do something
          break;
        case 38:  // up
          send(url,data,this);  
          break;
        }
     });
   }
});  

function send (url,data,this)
{
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var instance = this;
  xhr.open('POST', url, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () 
  {

    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) 
    {
      var text = xhr.responseText;
      var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(text);
      var filename = jsonResponse.filename;
      $(instance).closest('.parentDiv').children('.divToUpdate').text(filename);
    }
  }
  xhr.send(data);
}
```

How can I update correct div corresponding to where button is clicked ?

Comment: `this` is a reference to `document` in your case, as that's what the listener has been attached to. You may want to use `event.target`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot name an argument `this`. Instead set the desired context with the use of `.call()`: that way *send* will have `this` defined as you intend:

```
   send.call(this, url, data);  
   // ...

function send (url, data) // no this here
// ... you can use `this` here...
```

If you want the clicked element to be the value of `this` then call *send* as follows:

```
   send.call(event.target, url, data);
```